# Irreducible ideals are prime in polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $R$ the polynomial ring in $n$ variables over $k$. If $J$ is an irreducible ideal of $R$ then it is a prime ideal as well.

To establish this statement I have succeeded to show that J would be primary and it will follow if we can show that it is radical as well... but I am not seeing anything to establish it even using Nullstellensatz... any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot "establish this statement" because it is false!
For example $(X^2)\subset k[X]$ is irreducible but not prime.

**Remark** The correct implications (valid in any noetherian ring) are:$$ \text {prime}  \implies\text {irreducible}  \implies \text {primary}   $$

Comment: +1 very simple. Maybe the OP was hoping that the "irreducible implies prime" statement for elements in such a polynomial ring also held for ideals... but they're quite different.

Comment: Dear @rschwieb, you are right:  it is indeed confusing that non irreducible elements may generate irreducible principal ideals...

Comment: Thank you..could you just tell me how can we argue here that (X^2) is irreducible ideal..it is primary that I have understood!!...  @  Georges Elencwajg

Comment: @tandra There are only two ideals above $(X^2)$: just $(X)$ and the entire ring. You can't find a pair that intersects to $(X^2)$.